# Custom ui component from framework not rendered to story board

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode-storyboard

I am creating a swift framework which has some reusable UI components.

When I am importing this framework in another application, I am able to add custom component programmatically.

But, if I add UIView on storyboard and change its class to customComponent, I am not able to see its preview on storyboard. Due to this i cannot distribute this framework to other developers as they can't visualize the component in InterfaceBuilder.

Though, I can see the component at run-time, it reduces the effectiveness of using framework in storyboard.

I have followed a [link](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/getting-started-with-reusable-frameworks-for-ios-development-f00d74827d11) to develop swift framework.

Thre are two projects Library and SampleApp.

Libray : This is a swift framework which as one custom ui component as MyButton. its very basic ui just to avoid any confusion.

SampleApp : This application uses Library to show MyButton on sample screen

Please let me know the way i can see the preview of custom UI component from framework in any other application.

Edit1:

I have uploaded my sample code where I have applied the suggestions, but not able to resolve this.
[Code](https://github.com/manishjaswal/iOS_Lib_Sample)

Edit 2:
Rectified the broken link of tutorial. I have not used outlets just to make it simpler.

Edit 3:
There are two projects: Library and SampleApp

I have [MyButton.swift](https://github.com/manishjaswal/iOS_Lib_Sample/blob/master/Library/Library/MyButton.swift) as a custom widget in Library project.

I have added UIView in [StoryBoard](https://github.com/manishjaswal/iOS_Lib_Sample/blob/master/SampleApp/SampleApp/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard) and changed its class to MyButton(from library Framework)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there is!

After you import your framework:

```
import MyFramework
```

In IB, select the framework module:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Of course, I'm assuming you've made the custom components [`IBDesignable`](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/).

**EDIT #2:**

There should be no need to "import" into your storyboard. All you want to do is make sure that your view controller code has the `import` in it and that your storyboard's view controller is that subclass. For instance, here's a view controller named `MainViewController`:

[image]

And to set your view to be controlled by it:

[image]

Comment: How should I import framework in storyboard, as it is a xml code.  Yes, I have made my component as IBDesignable. I am able to see the widget at runtime, but not in Interface builder preview.

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Just `import` into the view controller that the storyboard "view controller" is pointed to. By default - in a single view project, it's called `ViewController`. I'll add a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: yes , i was doing that, but could not see the preview on story board. I have shared  the sample code. it will be very helpful if you could check and see what i am missing

Comment: I downloaded your sample. Not sure what I'm looking at though. On the "app" side, it's nothing. Storyboard and view controller code contain nothing. On the framework side I only see ".h" files, suggesting... Obj-C framework? Your question indicated otherwise.

Comment: there is one UIView on StoryBoard . I have changed its class to MyButton. its not visible as we are not able to see the preview on story board.But If you run it once you will be able to see the button on screen. Added the screenshot in question.